# How to find which area is bounded by those two graphs

Tags: calculus, geometry, area

Namely we have given two graphs: $y=\sqrt{2 - x^2} \text {and } x + (\sqrt{2}-1)y = \sqrt{2}$

The question asks us to find the area bounded by those two graphs. I tried sketching those two graphs in a plane, however still I'm not sure which area is the question asking to find?

The correct answer says $\frac{\pi }{4} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. Here is a picture of the two graphs. I would be really thankful if someone shows me how to approach to find the correct area.

[image: Sketch of the two graphs]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not think about graphs, but rather think about circles and lines in the plane instead.

[image]

The sector of the circle defined by the intersections with the line (the shaded region in the drawing above) are an 8th of the circle. So the whole sector has area $\frac18\cdot \pi\sqrt 2^2 = \frac\pi4$.

Now, this sector includes the region we are after, but also includes a triangle $\triangle ABO$ that we don't want. So we subtract the area of that triangle. It has base $\sqrt2$ and height $1$, so its area is $\frac12\cdot \sqrt2 = \frac1{\sqrt2}$. This gives you the answer you're after.

Answer (score 1):

Those two lines intersect at $\left(\sqrt2,1\right)$ and at $(1,1)$. So, you should compute the integral$$\int_1^{\sqrt2}\sqrt{2-x^2}-\frac{\sqrt2-x}{\sqrt2-1}\,\mathrm dx,$$which is indeed equal to $\frac\pi4-\frac1{\sqrt2}$.

Answer (score 1):

It is the area right of the blue line, below the green semicircle. $x$ varies between $1$ and $\sqrt 2$.

From geometrical consideration, you can calculate the area of the sector of the disk bounded by $(0,0)$, $(1,1)$, and $(\sqrt 2,0)$, then subtract the area of the triangle with the same vertices. so $$A=\frac 18 \pi R^2-\frac 12 Rh$$with $R=\sqrt 2$ and $h=1$.
$$A=\frac 18 \pi 2-\frac 12 \sqrt 2 1=\frac \pi 4-\frac {1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The question asks to find the area between the blue and the green line in the first quadrant. They are intersecting in two points there.

The easiest way would be to calculate the are under the line let us call it $A_l$ and then calculate the area under the arc let us call it $A_a$.

The answer you seek can you find by calculating

$$
A_a-A_l.
$$

Hope this helped